Should i use Moisture-proof Gypsum Board or Cement Board for the bathroom?
so basically im in the middle of building a new bathroom.
What walls would be best for it:
Moisture-proof Gypsum Board or Cement Board


I use cement board in all of the shower or around tubs and any areas that will be wet then moisture resistant for the remainder of the room , even the ceiling.

No type of gypsum board is suitable for use where there is regular contact with moisture. "Moisture-proof" is a lie.
